# appengine.GeoPointにjsonタグを付与したい

Tags: go, google-app-engine

GAE/Goでjsonを受け取り・返却するサーバーを作成しています。

さて、GAEのdatastoreにはGeographical point型(appengine.GeoPoint)がありますが、
これを以下のように構造体定義すると、GeoPointのLat, Lngの部分だけjsonのkey名を定義できません。

```
type MapItem struct {
    Id          string             `datastore:"-"`
    Name        string             `json:"name"`
    Description string             `json:"description"`
    Coords      appengine.GeoPoint `json:"coords"`
    Order       int                `json:"order"`
}
```

JSONで以下のようなデータを送れば、GAE/Goではうまく組み立ててくれるので良いのですが、
出来ることならばLat,Lngの部分をlatitude,longitudeとして与えたく思います。

```
{
    'name': "John Doe",
    'description': "Description...",
    'order': 123,
    'coords': {
        'Lat': 34.12345678, // ← latitude としたい
        'Lng': 135.1234567  // ← longitude としたい
    }
}
```

このような場合、どうすれば良いでしょうか。ご回答頂けますと幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`appengine.GeoPoint` は別パッケージ内で定義されていて、直接手がでない。タグ付きの `struct` は、型が異なるとされるので変換もちょっと難しい。そういうときは、 `type` で新しい型を作ってしまえば良いと思います。

```
type GeoPointJson appengine.GeoPoint
```

で、 `GeoPointJson` を定義。その型に Unmarshaller と、 Marshaller を定義してやれば、コードが冗長がちになりますが、安全に `GeoPoint` を拡張しつつ、それを自分の JSON 用 `struct` に組み込むことができます。

```go
func (g *GeoPointJson) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error)
... 
func (g *GeoPointJson) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
...
```

**実証コード**: https://play.golang.org/p/9N_ymtEJIn

```go
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

// ------------------------------
// Here, inside another package.
type GeoPoint struct {
    Lat, Lng float64
}
// ------------------------------

type GeoPointJson GeoPoint

type MapItem struct {
    Id          string       `json:"-"`
    Name        string       `json:"name"`
    Description string       `json:"description"`
    Coords      GeoPointJson `json:"coords"`
    Order       int          `json:"order"`
}

func (g *GeoPointJson) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    var jm map[string]float64
    if err = json.Unmarshal(b, &jm); err == nil {
        g.Lat = jm["latitude"]
        g.Lng = jm["longtitude"]
    }
    return
}

func (g *GeoPointJson) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    jm := make(map[string]float64)
    jm["latitude"] = g.Lat
    jm["longtitude"] = g.Lng
    return json.Marshal(jm)
}

func main() {
    encoded := `
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "description": "Description...",
        "order": 123,
        "coords": {
            "latitude": 34.12345678,
            "longtitude": 135.1234567 
        }
    }`

    mapItem := &MapItem{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(encoded), mapItem); err != nil {
        panic(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(mapItem.Name)
    fmt.Println(mapItem.Description)
    fmt.Println(mapItem.Coords.Lat)
    fmt.Println(mapItem.Coords.Lng)

    fmt.Println("----------------")

    mapItem.Name = "Modified Name"
    mapItem.Coords.Lat = 100.0
    mapItem.Coords.Lng = 200.0
    if jb, err := json.Marshal(mapItem); err == nil {
        fmt.Println(string(jb[:]))
    }
}
```

Output:

```
John Doe
Description...
34.12345678
135.1234567
----------------
{"name":"Modified Name","description":"Description...","coords":{"latitude":100,"longtitude":200},"order":123}
```

#### 補足: もう一つのやり方

```go
type MapItem struct {
    Id          string `json:"-"`
    Name        string `json:"name"`
    Description string `json:"description"`
    Coords      struct {
        Latitude  float64 `json:"latitude"`
        Longitude float64 `json:"longitude"`
    } `json:"coords"`
    Order int `json:"order"`
}
```

と定義して、

```
geoPoint := *(*GeoPoint)(unsafe.Pointer(&mapItem.Coords))
```

のように、メンバ `Coords` を直接 `GeoPoint` にキャストする方法もあります。こっちの方がコードが少ない（けど危なかしい）それでも良いなら、 https://play.golang.org/p/Qc60-KsYKl にサンプルコードを起きましたので、参考にしてください。